# Is $(A \land B)$ a form of $(p \land p)$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

This question is related to my previous question on forms of statements, here: [Rigorous definition of the set of forms of a propositional formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394808/rigorous-definition-of-the-set-of-forms-of-a-propositional-formula). Consider the propositional formula $(p \land p)$, where $p$ is a propositional atom. It is of the form $A$, and it is also of the form $(A \land A)$. But, I am unclear as to whether it is also of the form $(A \land B)$. Is $(A \land B)$ indeed one of the forms of the formula $(p \land p)$? Of course, we could ask an analogous question with a formula like $((p \land p) \land q)$, or $((p \land p) \land p)$. Basically, I want a precise definition of the forms of a statement, that would clarify my confusion.

Comment: Two equivalent ways of formalizing a proof system (specifically: propositional calculus): 1) with axioms in the language: $p \to (q \to p)$ and a rule for Substitution, and 2) with [schemata](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/): $\varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi)$.

Comment: See also the post [Substitution in Propositional calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109817/substitution-in-propositional-calculus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Answer given to that linked question will give you the proper definition to answer this question.

Consider: can you substitute sentences for $A$ as well as for $B$ such that $A \land B$ becomes $p \land p$? Answer: Yes. Just substitute $p$ for $A$ and substitute $p$ for $B$. So yes, $ p \land p$ is of the form $A \land B$ … meaning that $A \land B$ is a form of $p \land p$.

I suppose you are worried about the fact that we substituted the same statement $p$ for two different statement variables $A$ and $B$. But remember that $A$ and $B$ are just that: variables. So they could have the same value, just as in arithmetic the values of $x$ and $y$ in the expression $x + y$ can be the same.